# Determining if statement is even or odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

When referencing the following page (http://geneseo.edu/~heap/courses/239/activity3.pdf) which uses the definition of...

an integer $n$ is even if there exists an integer $k$ such that $n = 2k$

If you had $3n + 2 $ and assumed that $n$ was even you would substitute $n$ with $2k$...

$3(2k) + 2 = 6k + 2 = 2(3k + 1)$     since it is a multiple of $2$, it is even

However, if we had $3n + 3$ and assumed $n$ was even...

$3(2k) + 3 = 6k + 3 = 2(3k + 1.5)$
since there is a fractional result, could I conclude that it is not even?

Comment: in questions in number theory referring to evenness or oddness, or other modular arithmetic, I would advise against using decimals and fractions whenever possible as it might not even be defined in the domain you are working in.  That being said, depending on the instructor, points may be taken off for division for that very reason even if the numbers happened to work out nicely in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3(2k)+3=6k+2+1=2(3k+1)+1$ is odd.

Comment: This is not a complete proof: you have to show that if number is of the form $2k+1$ then it cannot be of the form $2k$. It is a simple step, but at this level it is something that you have to care about.

Comment: @giomasce: Of course, you are right:)

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a very basic question, you need a theorem that states that if there is a fractional result, then the number is not even. More precisely, you need to prove the following:

> If $n$ is even, so we have $n = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $n+1$ is not even, i.e., there is no $h \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n+1 = 2h$.

How do I prove this? Let us suppose that $h$ exists indeed: then $1 = (n+1) - n = 2h - 2k = 2(h-k)$. In particular $2$ divides $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. But this is clearly false, because in $\mathbb{Z}$ all divisors of a number must have smaller absolute value (bonus question: prove this rigorously, i.e., using the definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the properties of $\mathbb{N}$).